# Gzip files in task runner or at the server level?

Tags: apache, gzip, gulp

Putting the finishing touches on my task runner(Gulp)'s build task.  I'm wondering if it's better to gzip the file in gulp when I build the project or if it's better to set up Apache to gzip files somehow.

Are there any cons to gzipping at the server level?